# Why does my NSMutableString edit sometimes not work?

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablestring, nsscanner

I'm trying to repair some mis-numbered movie subtitle files (each sub is separated by a blank line). The following code scans up to the faulty subtitle index number in a test file. If I just 'printf' the faulty **old** indices and replacement **new** indices, everything appears just as expected.

```
//######################################################################
-(IBAction)scanToSubIndex:(id)sender
{
    NSMutableString* tempString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:[theTextView string]];
    int textLen = (int)[tempString length];
    
    NSScanner *theScanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:tempString];
    while ([theScanner isAtEnd] == NO)
        {
        [theScanner scanUpToString:@"\r\n\r\n" intoString:NULL];
        [theScanner scanString:@"\r\n\r\n" intoString:NULL];
        
        if([theScanner scanLocation] >= textLen)
            break;
        else
            { // remove OLD subtitle index...
            NSString *oldNumStr;
            [theScanner scanUpToString:@"\r\n" intoString:&oldNumStr];
printf("old number:%s\n", [oldNumStr UTF8String]);                
            NSRange range = [tempString rangeOfString:oldNumStr];
                [tempString deleteCharactersInRange:range];

            // ...and insert SEQUENTIAL index
            NSString *newNumStr = [self changeSubIndex];
printf("new number:%s\n\n", [newNumStr UTF8String]);
                [tempString insertString:newNumStr atIndex:range.location];
            }
        }
printf("\ntempString\n\n:%s\n", [tempString UTF8String]);
}

//######################################################################
-(NSString*)changeSubIndex
{
    static int newIndex = 1;
    // convert int to string and return...
    NSString *numString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", newIndex];
        ++newIndex;
    
return numString;
}
```

When I attempt to write the new indices to the mute string however, I end up with disordered results like this:

```
sub 1

sub 2

sub 3

sub 1

sub 5

sub 6

sub 7

sub 5

sub 9

sub 7

sub 8
```

An interesting observation (and possible clue?) is that when I reach **subtitle number 1000**, every number gets written to the mutable string in sequential order as required. I've been struggling with this for a couple of weeks now, and I can't find any other similar questions on SO. Any help much appreciated :-)

Comment: Maybe  scanning and modifying the string at the same time is causing the issues?

Comment: Thanks Sami, but the fact that it works fine after I hit subtitle 1000 in every test seems to rule that out. A string/byte size problem perhaps?

Comment: Why would it rule that out?

Comment: Because I'm still scanning and modifying the mutable string after sub 1000, but not getting the same bad number output. If that was the problem I guess It'd be bad for the entire run.

Comment: No, that’s not true. Many undefined behavior for example may be completely deterministic in some situations. First step is to remove possible unwanted behavior. For example, if replace 9 with 10 before the reading point, how would the scanner know it should move ahead one character and not read the one it’s pointing to at the moment?

Comment: My apologies Sami, it seems I was wrong :-(  I just tried setting the static counter in the 'changeSubIndex'  method to 1000 - assuming my code would run without error - but it still starts out producing garbage numbers... My approach is obviously the wrong way to go but I think I can fix it with a 'while' loop instead. Will post if successful. Thanks for feedback!

Comment: `[tempString rangeOfString:oldNumStr]` is finding numbers in a line with times.

Comment: Why don't you use your previous method: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63127546/how-can-i-modify-this-srt-file-parser and add that item to an array? It would be much easier.

Comment: Don't do this. 1) `scannerWithString:` accepts `NSString`, not `NSMutableString`. You're basically misusing it, violating API contract 2) You can use `replaceCharactersInRange:withString:` instead of `delete` & `insert` 3) `NSScanner` has a [`scanLocation`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsscanner/1413294-scanlocation?language=objc) property and I'd expect that you should update it after your `delete` & `insert`. An example: you delete `9`, insert `10` and the `scanLocation` is wrong now (different number of characters). I wouldn't rely on it even once you fix it.

Comment: @zrzka I tried to update `scanLocation` after `replaceCharactersInRange:withString:` but it doesn't work. It looks like `NSScanner` is buffering the string.

Comment: @Willeke thanks for testing (I didn't test it). I'm just gonna repeat that @Tom shouldn't do this, because no one knows what the `NSScanner` is doing with the `NSString` after the initialization (buffering or any other optimizations).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## NSScanner & NSMutableString

`NSMutableString` is a subclass of `NSString`. In other words, you can pass `NSMutableString` at places where the `NSString` is expected. But it doesn't mean you're allowed to modify it.

[`scannerWithString:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsscanner/1420483-scannerwithstring?language=objc) expects `NSString`. Translated to human language - I expect a string and I also do expect that the string is read-only (wont be modified).

In other words - your code is considered to be a programmer error - you give something to the `NSScanner`, `NSScanner` expects immutable string and you're modifying it.

We don't know what the `NSScanner` class is doing under the hood. There can be buffering or any other kind of optimization.

Even if you will be lucky with the mentioned `scanLocation` fix (in the comments), you shouldn't rely on it, because the *under the hood implementation* can change with any new release.

Don't do this. Not just here, but everywhere where you see immutable data type.

(There're situations where you can do it, but then you should really know what the *under the hood implementation* is doing, be certain that it wont be modified, etc. But generally speaking, it's not a good idea unless you know what you're doing.)

## Sample

This sample code is based on the following assumptions:

- we're talking about SubRip Text (SRT)
- file is small (can easily fit memory)
- rest of the SRT file is correct

  - especially the delimiter (`@"\r\n"`)

```c
@import Foundation;

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface SubRipText : NSObject

+ (NSString *)fixSubtitleIndexes:(NSString *)string;

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

```c
@implementation SubRipText

+ (NSString *)fixSubtitleIndexes:(NSString *)string {
    NSMutableString *result = [@"" mutableCopy];
    
    __block BOOL nextLineIsIndex = YES;
    __block NSUInteger index = 1;
    
    [string enumerateLinesUsingBlock:^(NSString * _Nonnull line, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
        if (nextLineIsIndex) {
            [result appendFormat:@"%lu\r\n", (unsigned long)index];
            index++;
            nextLineIsIndex = NO;
            return;
        }
        
        [result appendFormat:@"%@\r\n", line];
        
        nextLineIsIndex = line.length == 0;
    }];
    
    return result;
}

@end
```

Usage:

```c
NSString *test = @"29\r\n"
"00:00:00,498 --> 00:00:02,827\r\n"
"Hallo\r\n"
"\r\n"
"4023\r\n"
"00:00:02,827 --> 00:00:06,383\r\n"
"This is two lines,\r\n"
"subtitles rocks!\r\n"
"\r\n"
"1234\r\n"
"00:00:06,383 --> 00:00:09,427\r\n"
"Maybe not,\r\n"
"just learn English :)\r\n";

NSString *result = [SubRipText fixSubtitleIndexes:test];

NSLog(@"%@", result);
```

Output:

```
1
00:00:00,498 --> 00:00:02,827
Hallo

2
00:00:02,827 --> 00:00:06,383
This is two lines,
subtitles rocks!

3
00:00:06,383 --> 00:00:09,427
Maybe not,
just learn English :)
```

There're other ways how to achieve this, but you should think about readability, speed of writing, speed of running, ... Depends on your usage - how many of them are you going to fix, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the example code and detailed explanation of what NSScanner does 'under the hood' - which I wasn't aware of. It seemed like a possible solution at the time but your method is much more readable (and of course works). I appreciate your help  :-)